# How to prove that $ ¬∀x∈A, ¬P(x) \equiv \exists x\in A, P(x) $ using quantifier negation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm not needing assistance proving this statement.

$ ¬∀x∈A, ¬P(x) \equiv \exists x\in A, P(x) $

My first approach was to use demorgans laws but I'm having trouble with determining what to do next.

$ ¬∀x(x \in A, ¬P(x)) \equiv ¬\forall x(x \in A \wedge ¬P(x)) $

Comment: $\forall x \in A, \lnot P(x)$ means $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow \lnot P(x))$, not $\forall x (x \in A \land \lnot P(x))$.

Comment: Alright, How exactly do I show their equal though?

Comment: Just try for yourself first, but now with the correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

Quantifier negation is typically stated as:

**Quantifier Negation**

For any formula $\varphi(x)$:

$\neg \forall x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \ \neg \varphi(x)$

$\neg \exists x \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \ \neg \varphi(x)$

But in the case of qualified quantifiers, it would be:

**Qualified Quantifier Negation**

For any formula $\varphi(x)$ and set $S$:

$\neg \forall x \in S \  \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x \in S \ \neg \varphi(x)$

$\neg \exists x \in S \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x \in S \ \neg \varphi(x)$

If you were given the latter, then what you need to show is trivial:

$\neg \forall x \in A \ \neg P(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Qualified Quantifier Negation)}$

$\exists x \in A \ \neg \neg P(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Double Negation)}$

$\exists x \in A \ P(x)$

So, assuming you were *not* given the Qualified Quantifier Negation principle, but only the 'normal' one, you will indeed have to rewrite the qualified quantifier as an unqualified quantifier, but as indicated by @Magdiragdag, you didn't do this right.

In general, you have that:

**Rewriting Qualified Quantifiers as Unqualified Quantifiers**

For any formula $\varphi(x)$ and set $S$:

$\forall x \in S \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in S \rightarrow \varphi(x))$

$\exists x \in S \ \varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (x \in S \land \varphi(x))$

Applied to your problem, we thus get:

$\neg \forall x \in A \ \neg P(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Rewrite Qualified Quantifier)}$

$\neg \forall x (x \in A \rightarrow \neg P(x) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$

$\exists x \neg (x \in A \rightarrow \neg P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$

$\exists x \neg (\neg x \in A \lor \neg P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (De Morgan)}$

$\exists x (\neg \neg x \in A \land \neg \neg P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Double Negation)}$

$\exists x (x \in A \land P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Rewrite Qualified Quantifier)}$

$\exists x \in A \ P(x)$